# no encuentro el formato correcto para mostrar la hora por defecto en mi formulario html5

Tags: php, html5

codigo->

```
</tr>
<td><label for ="hora">hora:</label></td>
//input en donde se establecen dichos parametros`
<td><input type="time"  name="hora"  step="1"
       min="00:00" max="12:00" readonly  value="<?php echo time('h-m-s')?>"></td>
</tr>
```

Error en consola->

```
</tr>
<td><label for ="hora">hora:</label></td>
<td><input type="time"  name="hora"  step="1"
       min="00:00" max="12:00" readonly  value="<?php echo time('h:i:s A')?>"></td>
</tr>
```

Que solución me pueden dar. Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1):

Necesitas usar `date` en lugar de `time` asi:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td><label for ="hora">hora:</label></td>
<td><input type="time"  name="hora"  step="1"
       min="00:00" max="12:00" readonly  value="<?php echo date('h:i:s')?>"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Necesitas usar `date`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
</tr>
<td><label for ="hora">hora:</label></td>
//input en donde se establecen dichos parametros`
<td><input type="time"  name="hora"  step="1"
       min="00:00" max="12:00" readonly  value="<?php  echo date("H:i:s") ?>"></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: coloque date en ves de time y me sale dd/mm/yy eso ya lo tengo implementado en el formulario me falta es otro input con la hora actual.